# PHP delete first row of file till threshold is reached

Tags: php, trim, filesize

I want to trim my log-files to 7KB.
But the trimming just run once and the filesize will also not be updated.

Here is the code:

```
$thresholdKB = "7";
$files = glob('logs/*.{log}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($files as $file) {
    $filesizeKB = filesize("$file") / 1024;
    if ($filesizeKB > $thresholdKB){
        while ($filesizeKB > $thresholdKB) {
            $filesizeKB = filesize("$file") / 1024;

            $lines = file("$file"); 
            unset($lines[0]); 
            $fp = fopen("$file", 'w'); 
            fwrite($fp, implode('', $lines)); 
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `implode()`'s glue parameter may be completely omitted when the glue is an empty string.  The glue is an empty string by default.  ...but maybe you want to implode with newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of `filesize` are cached. You need to call `clearstatcache()` after updating the file.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: Whenever you feel like an answer is "simple/basic", this usually indicates that the solution already exists on Stack Overflow.   Before posting a new answer, have a quick check if you can find a duplicate.  It is always preferred to close close-able questions over answering them and generating redundant or off-topic content here.  Thank you for considering this civic duty which take more effort but ultimately helps the site more.